# Struts 2 <s:if> contains() method not working for string with multiple words

Tags: java, jsp, if-statement, struts2, contains

I've got the following code to print a message if the person's account is past due. (alert in this instance = "your account is past due")

```
<s:if test="%{#alert.contains('past due')}">
```

the code is not working. However if I pull out the white space and second word like this:

```
<s:if test="%{#alert.contains('past')}">
```

The code seems to work fine and the message gets printed.

Comment: #alert is a string object. Most definitely struts2.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with

```
<s:if test="%{#alert.indexOf('past due')>0}">
```

to test if the problem is related to the CharSequence parameter of the contains() method (that however should work except for one-character Strings)

Note that if the `alert` String is coming from a getter of the Action, you won't need the `#` sign because it is pushed on top of the stack

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine, but to get matches of substring better use `matches()` method.

```
<s:if test="#alert.matches('.*past due.*')">
```